# App unfortunately stopped when clicking button

Tags: android

I created an app with mp3 / mp4 buttons. When I click on the buttons the app unfortunately stops.

I searched a lot and I did not find any solution. Also I used Button onClick listener and it did not work.

Here is XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="61dp"
      android:layout_y="0dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mp3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:onClick="mp3"
        android:text="mp3" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mp4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:onClick="mp4"
        android:text="mp4" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorMultiSelectHighlight"
        android:onClick="about"
        android:text="About" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <WebView
      android:id="@+id/shared"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my main Java code:

```
package vk.com.downloadtosd;

public class SharedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView shared;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                setContentView(R.layout.shared);
                setTitle("Youtube Downloader");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Welcome to App",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    public void mp3(View view,Intent intent) {
        setContentView(R.layout.shared);
        setTitle("Youtube Downloader");
        shared=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.shared);
        String link=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if(link!=null){
            startWebView( "https://google.com/controller.php?type=mp3&urlid="+link);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Processing...Please Wait",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }


    public void mp4(View view,Intent intent) {
        setContentView(R.layout.shared);
        setTitle("Youtube Downloader");
        shared=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.shared);
        String link=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if(link!=null){
            startWebView( "https://www.google.com/controller.php?type=mp4&urlid="+link);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Processing ..Please Wait",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public void about(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"About me",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void startWebView(String s) {
        shared.setWebViewClient( new
                                         WebViewClient() {
                                             ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                                             public void onReceivedError
                                                     ( WebView view, int errorCode,
                                                       String description, String failingUrl) {
                                                 view.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/error.html" );
                                             }

                                             //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
                                             //  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                                             //    view.loadUrl(url);
                                             // return true ;
                                             //}
                                             @Override
                                             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                                                 if (view.getUrl().equals("www.google.com")) {
                                                     // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                                                     return false;
                                                 }
                                                 // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
                                                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                                                 startActivity(intent);
                                                 return true;
                                             }
                                             //Show loader on url load
                                             public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                                                 if (progressDialog == null ) {
// in standard case YourActivity.this
                                                     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SharedActivity.this );
                                                     progressDialog.setMessage( "Processing video..." );
                                                     progressDialog.show();
                                                 }
                                             }
                                             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                                 try {
                                                     if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                                         progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                         progressDialog = null;
                                                     }
                                                 } catch(Exception exception){
                                                     exception.printStackTrace();
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         });

        shared.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );

        shared.loadUrl(s);
    }

}//last
```

Comment: Updated Xml     https://vivekp.co/main.xml

Comment: Got the issue. When you use onClick through xml. Function should be public and accept only one argument View, In your case it accepting Intent also.

Comment: I removed my negative mark. It still having basic implementation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this to listen to onClick events marked on the XML file:

```
public void mp3(View view, Intent intent) {
```

to

```
public void mp3(View view) {
```

and same for mp4.

Please, never use phrases like "*Don`t mark as Duplicate or anything.*", moderators should always have the freedom to decide whatever they want.

Comment: Then How I pass the Intent to this mp3 onclick function

Comment: @Vicky that's another issue. Your question was about the app crash and I just answered one of you big problems. It's not recommended to mix problems here, for that purpose ask a new question after researching your new problem about Intents. Anyway, there's no need to use an Intent there, since you could capture it within `onNewIntent()`  and trigger the corresponding action.